# OEM as well as Generic GPU Driver wont work Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, gpu, amd-radeon

I am dealing with a major GPU driver issue. Last week I fresh installed Windows 10 on my old **Packard Bell Easynote LS11HR**.

After installing the generic GPU drivers for the **Intel HD 3000** and the **AMD Radeon HD 6650M**, the screen went black. Removing the drivers with DDU in safe mode and installing the OEM drivers solved this Problem, but some 3D Applications aren’t able to start with the old drivers.

Before the windows fresh install I didn’t noticed such problems. I guess that my Hardware is not compatible with the newest generic AMD driver, but how can I get the right GPU driver or do I need to install them in a different order? Switchable graphics may also be the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the Intel HD 3000 & the Radeon HD 6650M went out of support in 2015.
These crop up quite frequently on a gaming site I run support for, so the procedure is reasonably well-understood. It is always going to happen that one day underlying Windows 10 updates are going to leave these behind forever, but in the meantime, this often seems to work.

I wouldn't necessarily trust Windows to find the exact right drivers for either of them, so try the manual route.

The last full AMD driver release version was v15.7.1. There was one further beta driver released in Feb 2016.

The usual 'trick' for these is to *manually* clean install the 15.7.1 - there should be a clean install option if you use the advanced settings in the installer. Don't just let it install 'over the top' of anything else.

If the 15.7.1 works, leave it at that. If no joy then repeat the procedure, clean install the 16.2.1.

Both drivers are available directly from AMD at [AMD Radeon™ HD 6650M Drivers & Support](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/amd-radeon-hd-6000m-series/amd-radeon-hd-6650m)

The Intel HD 3000 was similarly abandoned by Intel at the release of Windows 10. There are no official Win10 drivers for it. Try the ones for Win8.1 from Intel directly - [Downloads for Intel® HD Graphics 3000](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81500/Intel-HD-Graphics-3000) or try the *Automatically update your drivers* section at the top of that page - some chipsets received one further driver release during the early Win10 cycle, primarily the HD 4000 series, but it's worth a look.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer Tetsujin. I’ve tried to clean install the 15.7.1, but there isn’t any advanced settings. If I am using DDU to remove the old driver it should be clean installed anyway.

However, the installation runs normally but after reboot I get a flickering black screen and a very slow boot, which instantly freezes after login.

Comment: Try the Intels first then. I don't have any system I can check against to see how you get to the advanced setup, but it's there somewhere. if DDU can definitely pull out the old drivers, then don't let the machine connect to the internet until you've got both drivers re-installed. Windows will grab whatever it thinks is the right driver & spoil your clean setup.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a driver available, get it from the Microsoft Catalogue. Open Device Manager, expand the Display section, right click on the driver and select Update. This will get it from the Microsoft Catalogue.

If that does not work, or the update fails, then there is not a driver for this machine. In this event, you can use VGA until the machine can be replaced.

Comment: Thank you for your answer John.
I tried the Microsoft Catalogue, but after installation of the AMD driver, Windows freezes and finally crashes. Right now only the VGA driver wont crash, but no application will switch to the discrete graphic card. Thus, no 3D Application is running smoothly. There must be something I can do, because the GPU worked as expected before the fresh windows install.

Comment: The install may be more up to date which would explain that part. Can you replace the card with a more compliant card? Would that be more than the value of the machine?

Comment: That could be the reason, but replacing the GPU wouldn’t be worth it. I got a decent PC at home, just for right now I would love to use this machine.